# PHP OOP File upload failure $_FILES not assigning to object/method variables

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I've been going over an old tutorial for OOP PHP and I've hit a wall
Here's the environment I'm in:

- WAMP(Apache) on Windows
- PHP 5.3.8

I've recently been trying to debug a section related to file uploads(images) using classes.

My problem starts at a place where I'm using a global variable $_FILES(file) as an argument and passing it into a method.

Which in turn processes(tests) the image file(Step 1) and then uploads it(Step 2).

I've discovered that the global variable assignment for the image is being "skipped" entirely even though
the var_dump shows the image array information with the error code 0 (i.e No errors)

array

- 'name' => string 'Westgantry.jpg' (length=14)
- 'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
- 'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php298.tmp' (length=22)
- 'error' => int 0
- 'size' => int 455568

The upload page form basically takes the post data and feeds it to the initialized photograph class - The upload form is seen below:

```html
<?php
       require_once("../../includes/initialize.php");
       //if session is not logged in redirect to the login page
         if(!$session->is_logged_in())
           { redirect_to("login.php"); }
 ?>
 <?php   
       $max_file_size = 1048576;
        $message = "";
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
           $photo = new photograph();
           $photo->caption = ($_POST['caption']);
           $photo->attach_file =($_FILES['file_upload']);

               if($photo->save())
          {
          //Success 
          $message ="Photograph uploaded successfully";
          }
          else
          {
          //Failure
          var_dump($_FILES['file_upload']);
          $message = join("<br/>", $photo->errors);
          var_dump($photo->debugMsg);
          }
        }
 ?>
        
 <?php include_layout_template('admin_header.php');?>
         <h2> Photo Upload </h2>
        
  <?php echo output_message($message); ?>
  <form action ="photo_upload.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data"  method="POST">
   
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size; ?>" />
        <p><input type = "file" name= "file_upload"/></p>
        <p> Caption: <input type="text" name="caption" value=""/></p>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Upload"/>
   </form>
        
   <?php include_layout_template('admin_footer.php'); ?>
```

The method in the photograph class that performs the first test(Step 1) is show here:

```html
 <?php
    
    public function attach_file($file)
    {
      $this->debugMsg = "Attach executing "; //Debug Test 1
    
      // Perform error checking on the form parameters
      if(!$file || empty($file) || !is_array($file)) 
       {
       // error: nothing uploaded or wrong argument usage
        $this->errors[] = "No file was uploaded.";
        return false;
       }
       elseif($file['error'] != 0)
       {
       // error: Display why attach failed
       $this->errors[] = $this->upload_errors[$file['error']];
       return false;
       }
       else 
       {
       // Set object attributes to the form parameters.
       $this->temp_path  = $file['tmp_name'];
       $this->filename   = basename($file['name']);
       $this->type       = $file['type'];
       $this->size       = $file['size'];
         
       }
    }
    
    ?>
```

Apparently its tripping at the first if condition before it is able to do any sort variable assignment.
I've gone through the standard checklist for php.ini to make sure its not a configuration issue listed below:

- file uploads = ON
- upload_tmp_dir = "c:\wamp\www\tmp"
- post_max_size = 8M
- upload_max_filesize = 2M  *I'm using files smaller than this limit
- max_execution_time = 30 seconds
- max_input_time = -1
- memory_limit = 128M

In addition to that I've also set all concerned folders to Everyone ie 777 (Even though Apache has full access anyway)
ACL in powershell confirms as much to ensure its not a read/write issue.

But still "no dice".

It's strange because every other stand-alone upload page file I've coded, works just fine 
 - Images practically load immediately. It's only when I try to code this way
that it pulls a "Dynamo" with the image array data i.e NULL or empty or vanished.

Interesting to note the tmp folder shows fragments of the session file, so at least I'm know the code is trying 
to make an attempt at loading the file.

If someone could tell me exactly what's happening between the POST['submit'] of $_FILES and the class method and why the file argument is being rejected 
that would be great.

Thanks in advance GF

Answer (score 0):

According to your snippets, you're using `$photo->attach_file()`as a property instead of a function.

Change the following:

```
$photo->attach_file =($_FILES['file_upload']);
```

to

```
$photo->attach_file($_FILES['file_upload']);
```

...removing the `=`.

You need to do the same with `$photo->caption` if that too is a function.

Comment: Alright, I've tried removing the assignment operator(=) but still getting the no upload result. . Interesting thought though - Trying a few combinations for this specific code line  (nb :Caption doesn't have a method)